# Database INSERT does not take place

Tags: php, mysql

My code is as follows:

```
<?php
include("config.php");

$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 

if($_POST['id'])
{
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $id = mysql_escape_String($id);

    $ip_sql=mysql_query("select ip_add from Voting_IP where mes_id_fk='$id' and ip_add='$ip'");
    $count=mysql_num_rows($ip_sql);

    if($count==0)
    {
        $sql = "update Messages set up=up+1  where mes_id='$id'";
        mysql_query($sql);

        $sql_in = "insert into Voting_IP (mes_id_fk,ip_add) values ('$id','$ip')";
        mysql_query($sql_in) or die(mysql_error());
        echo "<script>alert('Thanks for the vote');</script>";


    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script>alert('You have already voted');</script>";
    }

    $result=mysql_query("select up from Messages where mes_id='$id'");
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $up_value=$row['up'];
    echo "<img src='button.png' width='110' height='90'>";
    echo $up_value;

}
?>
```

My problem is that the insert process does not take place at all. The `script` tags echos an alert box. Even the `img` tag is echoed to the web page. But the insert process does not take place. The config file is fine.
Note: This code works on my local machine which has PHP 5.3 but it does not work on the server which has PHP 5.2.

Comment: Dumb question, but are you successfully connecting to the db in both cases?  That code isn't shown here.

Comment: yes i am successful.. again, the code works fine on my local server..but doesnot work on my wwebserver

Comment: But do you see the new value in the database?

Comment: nope..the insert process and the update process doesnot take place...just the alert box is displayed..

Answer (score 0):

The only explanation is that the `$count==0` check is false. Try with this workaround:

```
$ip_sql=mysql_query("select count(*) from Voting_IP where mes_id_fk='$id' and ip_add='$ip'");
$rc=mysql_fetch_row($ip_sql);
$count=$rc[0];
```

instead of:

```
$ip_sql=mysql_query("select ip_add from Voting_IP where mes_id_fk='$id' and ip_add='$ip'");
$count=mysql_num_rows($ip_sql);
```

Comment: the count condition works fine because i get the following alert:

     
    echo "<script>alert('Thanks for the vote');</script>";
as you can see, the above alert is inside the if condition, just below the insert statement.

Comment: Then it's the insert query there aren't other possibilities

Comment: i dont know why the insert query not inserting any values in the database. it works completely fine on my local server. but it doesnot work on my web server...

Comment: Yes i've understood it, but inside the if block there are only queries so the only problem can be with the insert query

Comment: Are you sure that your are connected to the db?

Comment: yea i am...cauz  on page load...it displays values from the database

Comment: No i dont' see any problem and if it doesn't die on the mysql_error there's no error. I really don't know. Try to print the query before execute it to see if it is all OK

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried messing around with the quotes?  Someone please correct me if I'm wrong, but AFAIK, variables within single quotes don't get expanded in PHP.

```
$ip_sql=mysql_query("select ip_add from Voting_IP where mes_id_fk='".$id."' and ip_add='".$ip."'");
```

Comment: They are single quotes inside double quotes so there's no problem but the quotes problem is frequent so it can be a solution

Comment: Almost right - $str = 'Hello $planet' wouldn't output the value of the $planet variable, but "Hello '$planet'" should. Note, the string is surrounded by single quotes in the first example, which means minimal parsing, the second example CONTAINS some single quotes, but is surrounded by double quotes, which means full parsing (including translation of variables).

Comment: Single quotes inside double quotes are treated like any other character, so if $a if 1, "'$a'" is '1'

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the answers and comments, it's time to get old school:

```
    $sql = "update Messages set up=up+1  where mes_id='$id'";
    echo $sql . '<br>';
    mysql_query($sql);

    $sql_in = "insert into Voting_IP (mes_id_fk,ip_add) values ('$id','$ip')";
    echo $sql_in . '<br>';
    mysql_query($sql_in) or die(mysql_error());
    echo "<script>alert('Thanks for the vote');</script>";
```

What are you looking for?

You are putting values in for $id and $ip - maybe one of them is empty or contains a character that is making the result "odd" in some way. By taking a good look at the raw query that you are about to execute, you'll see if the variable parts of it are upsetting things.

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking if the first query succeeds:

```
$ip_sql=mysql_query("select ip_add from Voting_IP where mes_id_fk='$id' and ip_add='$ip'");
$count=mysql_num_rows($ip_sql);
```

There's no `... or die(mysql_error())` there, but this is most likely not the problem, because if the query was failing, you'd get an "invalid statement handle" type error when you do the `mysql_num_rows()` call immediately afterwards. As a stylistic tip, I'd suggest rewriting the first query as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Voting_IP
WHERE (mes_id_fk = $id) AND (ip_add = $ip)
```

You're not using any of the retrieved values, just the row count, so there's no point in doing a "select *" type query, which forces the database to do at least SOME processing on all the possible values. If this system scales to very large numbers of votes and IPs, using the count() version will be more efficient.

You say the insert doesn't take place, but don't say which `alert()` occurs, which means either there's an error with the insert query, or your first query returns 0, and the whole block with the insert query is skipped.

Have you tried manually running the update/insert queries? You're not checking if the update succeeds, as there's no `or die(mysql_error())` afterwards. Perhaps there's a foreign key error, a syntax error, etc...

Answer (score 0):

If you're updating an entry based on an ID, then obviously you want to update and insert when the count is NOT zero.... or greater than zero,.. or 1

Simply taking out the == 0, should fix it

```
if($count)
{
    $sql = "update Messages set up=up+1  where mes_id='$id'";
    mysql_query($sql);

    $sql_in = "insert into Voting_IP (mes_id_fk,ip_add) values ('$id','$ip')";
    mysql_query($sql_in) or die(mysql_error());
    echo "<script>alert('Thanks for the vote');</script>";


}
```